# How do I test Azure ActiveDirectory locally?

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, ldap

I'm working on a solution which uses Azure ActiveDirectory for it's authentication backend. In the mean time, I'm attempting to setup a local testing environment - Since I don't have a machine with a Windows Server-grade OS available, can I use some sort of a substitute? Would a Ubuntu VM with Open LDAP work for this purpose?

Best regards

Comment: Maciek, does your local test infrastructure not have internet connection? If it does, can you tell me why the Azure AD cloud service doesn't suffice for you test cases/test app? You can create a test directory inAzure AD and use that - don't need to target your production directory.

Comment: Hi there, I'd prefer to have tests without any costs involved - not sure what the pricing on Azure AD currently is, but I think it's not free

Comment: The non-premium version is free. I believe it has all the capabilities that your test app would need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the WS-Fed protocol, OpenLDAP probably won't help.

Thinktecture's [EmbeddedSTS](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/22/announcing-thinktecture-embeddedsts-a-simple-local-sts-for-asp-net-applications/) was written specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Hi, at this point I haven't decided what to use yet - I'm considering using regular LdapConnection - since both AD and OpenLDAP should support it - right?

Comment: Azure AD does not support LDAP.  You'd have to spin up a VM with a full version of Active Directory.  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/fundamentals-identity/